# LAMP in linux mint

Tags: linux-mint

Is the LAMP stack available by default in the Linux Mint 20 Ulyana software repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux Mint is primarily a desktop distribution so Apache, PHP and MySQL/MariaDB are not installed by default, but are available in repositories so you can install them. You can install [tasksel](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/tasksel) first to help you with that:

`sudo apt-get install tasksel`, run `sudo tasksel` and install `LAMP server`.

or [install everything manually with apt](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/486):

`sudo apt-get install apache2 php mariadb-server`

Different versions of PHP can be found in [this PPA repository](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/).